# If type="date" drop User Interface is breaking in iPhone 10

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Image for reference:

[image: image for reference]

Other than plugins is there any possible way to rectify this issue?  Am aware that this has to be fixed from iOS team, but i need an alternative possible ways to sort out this issue.

**Note:** This issue is reproducible only in iPhone 10

Comment: @Gerard i have tried the above link but nothing worked for me. any other suggestions?